# Zebra datepicker select event

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using Zebra Datepicker I want to get selected value when the input value changed. But my code doesnt work. Please help me!.

```
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date1" value="Select First Date"/>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date2" value="Select Last Date"/>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.datepicker").Zebra_DatePicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
 });
    $("#date1").Zebra_DatePicker({
      onSelect: function() {
        $(this).change();
        alert("x");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the problem, this could be the solution

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").Zebra_DatePicker({ format: "d-m-y" }); 
 });
    $("#date1").Zebra_DatePicker({

          format: "d-m-y" ,
      onSelect: function() { 
        $(this).change();
        alert($(this).context.value);
      }
    });
```

Comment: strange, I've tested the issue here https://jsfiddle.net/giuseppe_straziota/0jqqfxf1/ and it works

Comment: Yes your fiddle is working. I will check my other file. Thanks for help.

Comment: thanks, check your browser console, maybe it's only a library dependencies issue. zebra needs jquery to work Good luck!

Comment: Doesnt seen any error and I loaded jquery before zebra js.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
  $('#date1').Zebra_DatePicker({
            onSelect: function (date) {
                alert(date);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't see this `onSelect` event in the docs.. spent so much time.

Comment: Working fine for me ( Zebra Datepicker @version 1.9.8 ). Thank you